# Can't deploy a model created with scikit-learn on ML Engine

Tags: deployment, scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to deploy a model created with scikit-learn on ML Engine. I worked on a Datalab notebook and after creating the model, I exported it to a file by using **joblib.dump (model, 'model.joblib')**. Once I had that file, I copied it in Cloud Storage: **gsutil cp ./model.joblib gs://..**. Finally, I created a model resource by typing: **gcloud ml-engine models create model --regions=us-central1**.
The problem comes when I try to create the model version, as it says that it expects to find a .pb/.pbtxt saved model file.
Does anyone knows how to proceed with this issue without having to move to a TensorFlow model?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Datalab, you are running an older version that doesn't support scikit learn. A new update to Datalab will be out any day now.

However, the workaround is simple. Just run

```
%bash
 gcloud components update
```

in a cell of your notebook

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a few flags, in particular `--framework` (which defaults to TensorFlow), but also `--runtime-version` (must be 1.4 or higher) and (possibly) `--python-version` (defaults to 2.7). Try something like ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart#create_a_model_version)):

```
gcloud beta ml-engine versions create v1 \
  --model my_model \
  --origin gs://path/to/model \
  --runtime-version="1.8" \
  --framework SCIKIT_LEARN
  --python-version="3.5"
```

For a list of what's contained in each runtime version (i.e. to help you choose which one), see [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list).

Comment: Thank you @rhaertel80, but it seems that **--framework** and **--python-version** are not valid arguments even if it's true that the example in the reference uses it... This is the error message I get:

**(gcloud.beta.ml-engine.versions.create) unrecognized arguments:
  --framework
  SCIKIT_LEARN
  --python-version=2.7 (did you mean '--runtime-version'?)**

Comment: Hi @David, most probably you are running an old version of the SDK, given that the `--framework` and `--python-version` flags were recently added to the SDK (as you will be able to see in the [Release Notes documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes)). You can check you current version by running `gcloud version`, and update it using `gcloud components update`. That should solve your issue with the *unrecognized arguments* error.